# Bandwidth throttling for S3 upload using AWS SDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using AWS SDK .net API to upload my files to S3 Account. Is there a way to control System Bandwidth while uploading files. Does AWS provide any API for throttling?

Answer (score 0):

try using the `InputStream` property of your `PutObjectRequest` and feeding a stream that does the throttling such as [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18243/Bandwidth-throttling)